# Issue while moving files from one folder to another with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, directory

I have multiple csv files in a directory and I am trying to split them in two different folders. If “colname” is found at any column or row then write the data to an excel file in outpath1. If “colname” is not found then move the file into outpath2. My code below is working fine until the line with “if not row_found:” because outpath2 has all the files that do not have “colname” but also files where “colname is found at row level. Is there a way to fix this or a better method to do this? Any help is welcome.

```
for fname in os.listdir(root_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, fname)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    col_found = False
    if "colname" in df.columns:
       col_found = True
       df.to_excel(out_path)
       if not col_found:
       for n, row in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
                row_found = False
                for value in row:
                    if value == "colname":
                        row_found = True
                            df.to_excel(out_path)
                    if not row_found:
                        out_path2 = os.path.join(out_dir2, fname)
                            shutil.copy(file_path, out_path2)
```

Comment: Are you declaring `row_title_found` anywhere before the code snippet you shared? Seems like we don't know what value that might have in this piece of code. Sharing the whole relevant code may help.

Comment: Actually I meant row_found.

Comment: You might want to test the conditions for `row_found` differently. What do you mean by your code is not working until that condition? What do you expect should happen and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 1):

> outpath2 has all the files that do not have “colname” but also files
>   where “colname is found at row level

That happens because `if not row_found` is inside the loop `for value in row`, to avoid this, move the if statement outside the for loop:

```
row_found = False
for value in row:
    if value == "colname":
        row_found = True
        df.to_excel(out_path)
if not row_found:
    out_path2 = os.path.join(out_dir2, fname)
    shutil.copy(file_path, out_path2)
```

or use a cleaner way, in which you don't need `col_found` nor `row_found`:

```
for fname in os.listdir(root_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, fname)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    if "colname" in df.columns or "colname" in df.values:
        df.to_excel(out_path)
    else:
        out_path2 = os.path.join(out_dir2, fname)
        shutil.copy(file_path, out_path2)
```

Comment: Hi @borfo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.